# ReadOnly TextBox causes page back when enter backspace key

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to use below code ([From Here](http://www.vijaykodali.com/Blog/post/2008/09/02/Disable-Backspace-to-Previous-Page-in-AspNet.aspx)) to avoid page back when pressing backspace key on a ReadOnly TextBox, but it is not working:

The code is within the `Master Page`, and the Content WebForm has the ReadOnly TextBox

```
    <head runat="server">
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Site Style Declarations -->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../css/reset.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../css/default.css" type="text/css" />  

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">            
        function cancelBack()   
        {   
            if ((event.keyCode == 8 ||    
               (event.keyCode == 37 && event.altKey) ||    
               (event.keyCode == 39 && event.altKey))   
                &&    
               (event.srcElement.form == null || event.srcElement.isTextEdit == false)   
              )   
            {   
                event.cancelBubble = true;   
                event.returnValue = false;   
            }   
        }  
    </script>

</head>
<body onkeydown = "cancelBack()">
```

But when press the BackSpace key in the ReadOnly TextBox from the Content Webform it keeps going to the previous page, any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Is there a benefit for making the textbox read-only instead of disabling it so that they can't get into it at all?

Comment: I thought in that possibility but sometimes the text in the textbox is bigger than the size of it, so it would be nice to have it readonly to be able to read the entire text :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add the attribute `onkeydown = "cancelBack()"` also on the textbox?

if you need to do it in javascript :

```
$(":text[readonly]").keydown(function() { cancelBack(); });
```

Comment: In every ReadOnly textbox? The idea on this code is to avoid that :|

Comment: you can add the attribute dynamically with one line of javascript if you need

Comment: you should put all the relevant code in your question (i.e. textboxes). Where you put that line I suggested, is it hitting a breakpoint in the function `cancelBack()` if you try debugging?

Comment: I just tried putting the onkeydown in the textbox: `<asp:TextBox ID="txtBrand" runat="server" Width="300px" ReadOnly="true" onKeyDown= "cancelBack();"></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: does it enter the `cancelBack()` function that way? If yes, check what condition is preventing to enter in the `if`. I suspect you should remove `&&    
               (event.srcElement.form == null || event.srcElement.isTextEdit == false)`